# Symfony2 fosUserBundle Change Password prevent nested form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, nested, fosuserbundle

How do i prevent the form - rendered through the Symfony2 - FosUserBundle - being nested?
The builder has two field, on of them is repeated field. It seems that this is goind to be rendered as nested

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('current_password', 'password', array(
        'label' => 'form.current_password',
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => new UserPassword(),
    ));
    $builder->add('new', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password_confirmation'),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ));
}
```

What i get, when the form is rendered is this:
http://pastebin.com/Np2bvgvH

As you can see, the repeated form fields are wrapped in another "FormRows"-div. I want them to be simple "FormRow"-divs without the extra FormRows. The Layout isn't meant to have two nested FormRows

I hope you understand my issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Symfony take into account this type of fields.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to redefine the repeated_row block

```
{% block repeated_row %}
{% spaceless %}

    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_row(child) }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock repeated_row %}
```